# The plane formed by the base of a cone transformed to x-y coordinates

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a random 3-d walk where you can go either positive x,y,z by one step. After 1000 steps you most likely end up on concordant 333,333,333. I have a visual of 2000 trials. [image: 3dwalk] I want to plot the ending points onto a 3-d histogram. I believe it should look like a 3-d Gaussian. My problem is that if you take the ending x-y coordinates directly and plot them, you get an oval shape. I think that's kind of expected. These ending points lie on the plane formed by the end of the random walks. Here is a picture of the histogram [image: Histo] Here is a picture of a 2-d plot of the x-y ending points. [image: 2-d] How to I transform the ending points from my "cone" to accurate x-y coordinates. I think the 2-d would look like a circle. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want a graph that looks more like a circle, consider plotting against the ending plane (which you describe) instead of `x` and `y`.  If you transform your results to use coordinates like an isometric projection:

```
x' = x - (y + z)/2
y' = y - (x + z)/2
z' = z - (x + y)/2
```

e.g.:

```
    z'
    |
    |
   / \
  /   \
x'     y'
```

then convert that to a 2d version that pleases you.

```
x'' = sqrt(3) * (y' - x')/2
y'' = z' - (x' + y')/2
```

---

If you want to understand how this was accomplished, just think of looking directly down from the vector (k, k, k) to the origin from infinitely far away, with 'up' pointed towards the `z`-axis.  You would see (1,0,0), (0,1,0), and (0,0,1) forming an equilateral triangle, and simple geometry can give you the coordinates.  You can even skip the first `xyz -> xyz'` steps, that was to attempt to make it easier to understand, but might make it seem more confusing.

You can also search for "isometric projection", or take a look at this chart:

[image: projection methods]

and this online calculator:

https://planetcalc.com/8316/

Comment: Hello thank you for your response. Maybe I'm interpreting it wrong. I end up with some arrays for x,y,z endpoints. They are all like x,y,z = [333,331,...] They are all different and the elements from the 3 arrays add up to 1000. I put all these values in the equations above and I get a line. I know with my question, the origin I want to plot my values on is like 333,333,333. Then it should form a circle around this point. In your equations every x ' ' is a negative value. Thank you so much for your help. It also maybe be my code even though I checked it a few times

Comment: @ChrisBolig try again, I forgot a minus sign and didn't even finish the equation properly, so the line was expected. So sorry!

Comment: It works great, thank you so much. Is there any topics you could link me or I could look up to understand the math. I would google 3d plane to xy plane and get some complicated stuff. So if there is anything you could recommend I look up, I would appreciate it.

Comment: Thank you so much, great help